# joining the same pthread multiple times

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

the flow in my program calls `pthread_join(thread_id, nullptr);`
2 times for the same `thread_id` from the same calling thread.

First time the call returns successfully but the second time it just hangs indefinitely. The documentation does not say clearly that it's forbidden to call pthread_join multiple times for the same thread_id. Is it indeed the case?

*I know that I can implement thread synchornization using pthread_cond_t but I would like to understand pthread_join limitations first.*

Comment: That doesn't make sense: `pthread_join` returns when the thread being joined on has ended. A thread can't end more than once... Additionally: the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) states: *Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.*

Comment: The documentation clearly states "If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately".
So it does make sense if different parts of the program are interested to check whether their child process ended.

Comment: @Roman: "already terminated but not yet joined" and "already joined" are completely different things. **Any** use of a `pthread_t` after `pthread_join` on it is extremely dangerous undefined behavior (it's a use-after-free type bug).

Comment: I was using join as syncronization mechanism to ensure that the back-ground task has been finished and I needed to check this from multiple points in my program. I guess using join for synchronization is conceptually wrong. Not sure what's the correct use-case for it though....

Comment: One join() is one time too many:(

Comment: Some of the usecases are: 1) use it to wait for a thread to terminate (as you can only do this once, you'll need to store the information in the joining thread and provide a way for other threads to retrieve the status), 2) to get a return value from a thread, and 3) to clean up the resources used by the thread (you need to do this either by joining the thread, or by detaching it - otherwise you risk running out of thread resources).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for `pthread_join`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) - in the Notes section it is stated that:

> Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.

Lots of other good information on joining threads (and other aspects, if you search for some of the other pthread functions) in the link too.

Comment: Thanks! I can not believe that I missed that line :(